# Collision Detection With Polygons

Tags: java, android, collision-detection, polygon

I was wondering if anyone could give me an idea on how to implement first a class to define a polygon, and second how to detect collisions between two polygons using this class. I am working in Java on Android to be more specific, though I can use the NDK for C/C++ too. I think to define my polygon I will just need an array of vertices right?

When I do the collision detection I have read things about the Separation Axis Theorem and GJK algorithm. Is this the right way to go, or am I making this too complicated. Just trying to get started in the correct direction. Thanks!

Comment: You're pretty much on the right track. There is really no easier option if you want the collision to work properly.

Comment: I found a pretty great explanation of Separation Axis Theorem on this site http://www.codezealot.org/archives/55

Comment: [This](http://www.metanetsoftware.com/technique/tutorialA.html) is also really good. A tutorial from the guys who made N

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You sound like you're fairly new to this kind of thing, and this is maybe a bigger question that you realize.

I think you'd do best to define the problem your trying to solve first, and then find a solution that solves that problem.

Let me ask you some qualifying questions:

are you talking about 2d or 3d?

Is this for a physics system?

do you need to know where they intersect or just if they intersect?

do you need to do a boolean operation on the shapes (like get the intersection or the union or something)?

Comment: I am working in 2D, and yes this is for a physics game. My goal is to have a ball in the world bounce around off all of the objects. I currently have rectangles and it works, but I wanted to add some images that I can create polygons for using predefined vertices. Based on where the objects collide I was hoping to bounce the ball off of.

Comment: For physics you need a few things that sound easy but turn out to be very difficult in practice:
1) you need extremely precise information about how the polygons game into contact (not just that they are in contact). This turns out to be hard.
2) you need to be able to resolve collisions between multiple moving objects. This is also hard.
If what you want to do is write a physics library and sort of pretend you're writing a game, then look up "Erin Catto". He's written a bunch of stuff about this. If you want to write a game, go get a (free) implementation of the Box2D physics library

Comment: That may very well be what I end up doing. I have looked into using Box2D but was hoping to try and get this working myself, just wondering whether learning Box2D would take longer than trying to implement this manually. Thanks.

Comment: sorry, I keep hitting "return" by accident.  Using Box2D may take a little time, but not too much. Unless you're making "Pong" a physics engine will take you many, many months to get working right, and you'll be fiddling with it forever after that.

Comment: Yea I know what you mean, I think Box2D it is. I may need to port my code over to LibGDX to make it a little easier to work with. But luckily I'm not too too far into the game yet.

Comment: That is a good decision. You will be able to learn it very quickly. What language / environment are you working with?

Comment: I'm working in Java on Android. I have quite a bit of experience with it, just haven't taken the plunge into real physics as of yet haha

Comment: go here: [box2d](http://code.google.com/p/box2d/downloads/list) and read the GDC presentations, then go here: [Chris Hecker](http://code.google.com/p/box2d/downloads/list) and read the physics articles.  Then you can make an informed decision about writing your own vs. using something pre written

Comment: Thanks, I will read about all of that. I think I am going to go the Box2D route, I will be happier in the end. Though I don't need all of its features as of yet, it wont hurt to have em handy and will save me a lot of work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @JohnPaquin Welcome to SO. Have a look at the FAQ to understand how things work here. Maybe you can merge the answers you gave in the comments into the actual answer? The topic is quite popular and it would be nice to have a good accepted answer for it. In general: if information in a question is not sufficient, ask question about it in the comments and let the OP adapt the question to them.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the type of polygon.

If your polygons are convex then an ordered list of vertices will describe one and both separating axis and GJK will be applicable algorithms.

If your polygons are concave but simple (ie, the edges never intersect) then an ordered list of vertices is still sufficient but neither separating axis or GJK is suitable.

If your polygons are complex (ie, edges may intersect) then you'll need the vertex list and a filling rule. The rule established which parts of the plane are considered to be inside the polygon and which are outside.

For example, imagine a polygon like a pentagram:

[image]

The difference in filling rules is the difference in whether the five-sided hole in the middle is part of the polygon or simply a hole.

All of the more complicated types of polygon can be broken down into multiple instances of the simpler kinds of polygon so it's quite normal just to put a flag in the ground and declare that you're interested in convex polygons only — that's exactly what GPUs do, for example.

Assuming you're defining collisions as simply whether or not two polygons overlap, the separating axes theorem is very simple and definitely the way to go. If you're planning to produce a scene with lots of polygons then you'll probably also want a broad phase, which is a quick way to flag a whole bunch of polygons as definitely not overlapping before you do the expensive test to find out which of the remainder still are.

An obvious example is bin sorting — suppose you divided your screen into 16 pixel vertical strips then for each polygon you could (i) determine which bins it touches; (ii) test it against all polygons already in those bins; (iii) add it to the bins. That'd probably mean you never even consider applying the test quite a lot of the time. That specific scheme has some obvious problems, depending on your scene, but smarter algorithms exist.

Comment: This is a great explanation, thank you! I'm thinking Box2D might be the route I should go. I am really interested in implementing this but it may be a lot easier and more useful to me to make use of a complete physics library. I really appreciate your answer.

Comment: That's probably not a bad idea. I've been doing this stuff for years and a quick look at some code shows that I've managed to do rigid convex bodies with hard constraints in about 1,500 lines and — completely separately — non-convex bouncy bodies with soft constraints in about the same, but if you wanted to throw in all the stuff Box2D does (which is a lot more than either of my 1,500 pieces of work) and make it as efficient you'd have to do a lot more than that and be very careful about it. It's a really interesting area though.